# How to create Spring Boot with Barcelona Primefaces Theme?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-boot, primefaces

I am using this repository: https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme to start a Spring boot project with Primefaces.

On the other hand, I have bought the Primefaces Barcelona (https://www.primefaces.org/barcelona/docs.xhtml).

Since I saw some post related to avoiding use web.xml in Spring Boot, I don't know how can I put all the configuration to install the theme.

Anyone know how can I do it?

The project structure is:

[image: Project Structure]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The theme is a jar, nothing more, noting less... So effectively you ask 'how can I use an external jar in spring boot'... Nothing JSF, nothing PrimeFaces related

Comment: Please note that my theme is far from finished. You could use it as a starting point, but you might probably have to add some styling here and there (especially for the more exotic components).

Comment: @JasperdeVries I know and I appreciate your work. It's my starter point of the project. To add the primefaces and the theme is what I am asking for

Comment: The theme is a library, not a web application, so you should not use it as a starting point for a web application.

Comment: I did not explain myself properly. Your application is the starting point. Is a little POC that I am creating. I am trying to add PF and Barcelona Theme inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I added all-themes manually and worked, but I not sure if this is the correct way using Spring Boot.